# count the number of times a number (factor) occurs within each group

Tags: r, dplyr

With the reproducible data below,

```
dat <- data.frame(Bin = rep(1:4, each = 50), 
                  Number = sample(5, 200, replace = T, prob = c(1,1,1,2,3))) 

> head(dat)
  Bin Number
1   1      3
2   1      5
3   1      4
4   1      5
5   1      5
6   1      1
```

I want to count the number of times each `Number` occurs within each `Bin`, preferably using `dplyr.`  Said differently, how many occurrences of each level of `Number` are in each `Bin`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `table` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dplyr has a count function which does exactly this.

```
dat %>% count(Number,Bin)
```

Answer (score 3):

Might as well throw the `data.table` answer here as well:

```
setDT(dat)[ , .N, keyby = .(Number, Bin)]
```

And as user20650 pointed out, `base` R has a very simple solution:

```
with(dat, table(Number, Bin))
```

Just depends on your preferred output format.

Comment: or even shorrter `table(dat)` or  `as.data.frame(table(dat))`

Comment: @user20650 yes, I'm assuming there are other columns in the actual table, but that works on this example. This approach is also more flexible (if OP wants to switch rows & columns, e.g.)