# count the number of times a number (factor) occurs within each group, for each column in the dataframe

Tags: r

As the title suggests I'm trying to extend the question asked here:

[count the number of times a number (factor) occurs within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246537/count-the-number-of-times-a-number-factor-occurs-within-each-group)

But for all columns in a given dataframe. A reproducible example below:

```
dat <- data.frame(Bin = rep(1:4, each = 50), 
                  Number = sample(5, 200, replace = T, prob = c(1,1,1,2,3)),
                  Number2 = sample(5, 200, replace = T, prob = c(1,1,1,2,3)))


> head(dat)
  Bin Number Number2
1   1      4       2
2   1      5       5
3   1      4       4
4   1      4       1
5   1      5       5
6   1      5       3
```

I can do it by multiple dcasts.

```
dcast(dat, Bin ~ Number)
dcast(dat, Bin ~ Number2)
```

However, my actual dataframe has many more columns.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually it is the same solution by Ronak Shah but a little bit simpler.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Bin) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_fn = length, names_sort=TRUE)

# A tibble: 8 x 7
    Bin name      `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 Number     10     7     3    10    20
2     1 Number2    10     6     6     8    20
3     2 Number      2     7     6     8    27
4     2 Number2     2     5     8    13    22
5     3 Number      3     8    13    12    14
6     3 Number2     9     5     6     7    23
7     4 Number      9     6     7     3    25
8     4 Number2     2     7     8    19    14
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, Patricio. Works beautifully, and would work on any dataframe irregardless of the other column names.

Answer (score 2):

Get the data in long format and use `count` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Number')) %>%
  count(Bin, name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, Ronak. The reason I have accepted the answer by @Patricio Moracho over yours, is because whilst in the exampe I did name the other columns with the same prefix it doesn't actually happen in my dataframe (probably my mistake), however, their answer does this based on any dataframe and not just the example I provided.

Comment: I completely agree. The only reason I accepted the other answer was for clarity for other people. Whilst it was probably an oversight on my part giving the two columns the same prefix, I feel it is still of the most benefit to others to have the most 'generalisable' answer as the accepted. 
Thank you again for taking the time to provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the base-R function `tabulate`...

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Bin) %>%                              #group by bin
  summarise(across(everything(), tabulate)) %>%  #for everything else generate a tabulation
  mutate(no = row_number())                      #add numbers being tabulated

# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   Bin [4]
     Bin Number Number2    no
   <int>  <int>   <int> <int>
 1     1      7       3     1
 2     1      9       6     2
 3     1      5       8     3
 4     1      9      16     4
 5     1     20      17     5
 6     2      4       5     1
 7     2      5       4     2
 8     2      8      10     3
 9     2     11      13     4
10     2     22      18     5
11     3      6       6     1
12     3      6       9     2
13     3      7       5     3
14     3     11      13     4
15     3     20      17     5
16     4      3       7     1
17     4      3       6     2
18     4      7       4     3
19     4     19      12     4
20     4     18      21     5
```

So, for example, bin 1, number 4 (the final column) has 9 in `Number` and 16 in `Number2`

Answer (score 0):

With base R, you can use `apply` family of functions and `table`:

```r
as.data.frame(apply(dat[, 2:ncol(dat)], 2, table))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `recast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
recast(dat, id.var = 'Bin', Bin + variable ~ value, length)
```